# Angular ng-view slide animation entering and leaving elements are placed one below the other

Tags: angularjs, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am trying to animate ng-view directive. As the first element leaves, it translates in the x direction towards right, and when the next element enters, it translates in the x direction but from the left side as shown in the following figure.

[image: ngView Slide in animation]

But the problem is the elements are placed one below the other. The incomming element infact is placed left to the outgoing element, but below. If I inspect I see that the divs are placed one below the other. I am using bootstrap, so is it playing any role here? How can I make them side by side instead of one below the other?

[image: ngView Slide in animation inspect]

Here is the css

```
.step1Slide{
    opacity:1;
}

.step1Slide.ng-enter {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    z-index: 10;
    transition:transform 3s linear;
}

.step1Slide.ng-enter-active {
    transform: translateX(0);
    z-index: 10;
    transition:transform 3s linear;
}

.step1Slide.ng-leave {
    transform: translateX(0);
    z-index: 1;
    transition:transform 3s linear;
}

.step1Slide.ng-leave-active {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    z-index: 1;
    transition:transform 3s linear;
}
```

And the html

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="registerNgView" class="step1Slide" ng-view>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was tackling this same problem. Found a semi-work around by changing the leave classes into "absolute". This isn't so elegant, but functional. The outgoing div doesn't get pushed down. If you weren't using Bootstrap's relative placement, this could easily be fixed.